# Every point in the open set is a limit point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that closed set contains all of its limit points. However, I can claim a statement: Every point in the open set $O$ is a limit point.

Here is my proof: Suppose $x \in O$. By definition, $\exists V_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq O$. Hence, there must be an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $\forall V_{\epsilon}(x) \cap O =$ points are different from $x$.

Example: $\left(0,1\right)$ is an open set. Although it does not contain $\left\{0,1\right\}$ which are its limit points, every element of this open set is a limit point by definition.

Is my proof and example correct? I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Every point of an open set is a limit point. But this doesn't say that these are the only limit points. Does it??

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Yes.

Comment: You need to be quite careful with your definitions. If you are essentially working with the real numbers and the definition of open set which comes from the associated metric, you will be fine. This seems to be implied by your tag "real analysis". But there are examples of more general topological and metric spaces where it is not true that every point of an open set is a limit point. In the real numbers a point in an open set is surrounded by some open ball of radius $\epsilon\gt 0$ and any point at distance $\frac {\epsilon}2$ is within that ball. Such points need not exist in general.

Comment: @MarkBennet I thank you very much. So, my result is only true in the real metric space, correct ?

Comment: There are lots of metric spaces and your result is true in some of them including real metric spaces of positive dimension.

Comment: Consider a non-empty set $X$ and the [discrete metric](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteMetric.html). Then $X$ is open, but $X$ does not have *any* limit point. The result however is true if there is a guarantee that every deleted neighbourhood is nonempty.