# Is it true that limit points of set of limit points don't exist?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it true that limit points of set of limit points don't exist ?

I am not getting any example in which set of limit points has any limit point.

Comment: What are the limit points of $[0,1]$?

Comment: You're probably thinking of more canonical examples of limit points like those of discrete sets. You may wish to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088283/every-point-in-the-open-set-is-a-limit-point?rq=1

Comment: @Nitin then does there exist any other possibility of limit points of set of limit points other than empty or set itself ?

Comment: Take $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$. What you *can* show in general is that the set of limit points of the set of limit points of a set is contained in the set of limit points of the set ($E'' \subset E'$); in other words, the set of limit points is *closed*.

Comment: @Nitin got it. Smart example !

Comment: To generalize the example given by @Nitin, take any [perfect set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set), which is by definition a set which is closed (so it contains all of its limit points) and has no isolated points (so all of its points are limit points). Any perfect set is equal to its set of limit points. A non-interval example of such a set is the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)

Comment: Perhaps you are mistaken about the definition of a limit point.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I got answer now. I was not able to find an example though it was straight forward. Thank you..

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the simplest example is the discrete topology, Let $X$={1,2,3,...,n}.We shall define discrete topology on it.Clearly each of $1,2,3,...,n$ are limits of {1},{2}, {3},..., {n} respectively.There collection  {1,2,...,n} has limit points $1,2,...,n$.

Comment: No, there are other topologies on a finite set than the discrete topology. The indiscrete one for example. Topologies on a finite set are in one-to-one correspondence with preorders on it. Moreover a discrete space has no limit point. Indeed every singleton $\{x\}$ is open.

Comment: I apologies;I shall edit my answer.Actually, I was thinking of discrete metric

Comment: Why i'm downvoted,Please explain,why I'm wrong.

Comment: I guess because everything in your post is wrong, as explained above in my comment, including your comment about discrete metrics.

Comment: @Subhajit Saha What is your definition of limit point? Lets take Wolfram's definition "The topological definition of limit point p of A is that p is a point such that every open set around it contains at least one point of A different from p". Now in  your discrete set every singleton is an open set so the point itself can not be a limit point.

Comment: @AHandsomeAlien,I am wrong,I forgot the fact that there has to be another point except p.I apologies to all